# Showing that $r(T)\leq \omega(T)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators from $E$ to $E$. Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$. The numerical range of $T$ is defined as follow
$$W({ T})=\{\langle Tx\;|\;x\rangle:\;x \in E,\;\;\|x\|=1\}.$$
 The numerical radius $\omega(T)$ of $T$ is defined by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\omega(T)
&=&\sup\left\{|\lambda|,\;\lambda\in W(T)\right\}\\
&=&\sup\{|\langle Tx\;|\;x\rangle|,\;x\in E,\;\|x\|=1\;\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Moreover, the spectral radius of $T$ is given by 
$$r(T)=\sup\{|\lambda|,\;\;{\lambda \in \sigma(T)}\},$$
where $\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum of $T$.

Why we have
$$r(T)\leq \omega(T)??$$

Thank you, everyone !!!

Comment: Theorem 1.1 in this reference could be helpful but the definition of the joint numerical radius is not the one given in my definition. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410492.pdf

Comment: Now reposted to MathOverflow: [Another concept to show that $r(T)\leq \omega(T)$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/279095). [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo) gives, in my opinion, very reasonable advice about cross-posting. Of course, other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting] might be of interest, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a one-line proof. See Theorem 1.1 in Moshe Goldberg, Eitan Tadmor: [On the numerical radius and its applications](http://www.cscamm.umd.edu/tadmor/pub/linear-stability/GT%20numerical%20radius%20LAA82.pdf), doi: [10.1016/0024-3795(82)90155-0](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(82)90155-0).

Comment: I fixed it. Try again please.

Comment: Ok, good luck !

Comment: Yes, maybe a bounty will buy someone's time to sort out your reading problems.